# How to update data to other components after a button is clicked

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am a beginner and I want to know how to update a component with data only when I click a button present in another component.

I am trying to implement an add-to-cart functionality on a practice project and I want to update the product count when I click on the add-to-cart button, but somehow I am not able to do when I try using the use state hook the add to cart button acts as a flag (ie after the button is clicked and counter is increased the data is updated ).

This is a [LINK](https://github.com/amitkrsingh102/e-com-test) to the repository.

Thanks

I want to add items to the cart only when I click add to the cart and not when I increase the counter.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by having a parent component that controls both state and the function that will change the state.
In my example I'll show how I did it.

I created a function `handleButtonClick()` on the `App` component. Whenever its called, it will find my selected item and update its quantity by adding it 1.

I pass this function into my `BuyItemButton` component, for it to be called when the user clicks on the `<button />` element.

I then pass into my `DisplayCart` component the `cart`. Displaying all my items in my `cart`.

```js
const {useState} = React;

const App = () => {
  const [cart, setCart] = useState([
    {name: "Soda", quantity: 0},
    {name: "Coffee", quantity: 0},
    {name: "Chips", quantity: 0},
    {name: "Chocolate", quantity: 0},
    {name: "Breadsticks", quantity: 0},
  ]);
    
  const handleButtonClick = (item) => {
    setCart((prevCart) => prevCart.map(product => {
      if (product.name != item.name) return product;
      
      return {
        ...product,
        quantity: product.quantity + 1,
      }
    }));
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {cart.map((product) => (
          <li key={product.name}>
            <BuyItemButton item={product} onClick={handleButtonClick} />
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <DisplayCart cart={cart} />
    </div>
  );
};

const BuyItemButton = ({item, onClick}) => {
  return <button onClick={() => onClick(item)}>{item.name}</button>
}

const DisplayCart = ({cart}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Items in my cart: </h1>
      {cart.map((item, index) => (
        <p key={item.name}>
          {item.name}: {item.quantity}x 
        </p>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <App />
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```